# PowerApps - split Collection into smaller Collections based on database data

Tags: database, collections, powerapps

### Short form of my question: Is there a way to split a Collection into several sub-Collections, based on SQL database entries?

**Update**

Okay, a simpler version, perhaps. I'm *really* struggling with this...

I start with a collection: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList**

It looks like this:

```
Result
REQ1991799.RITM2280596.01 
REQ2048874.RITM2349401.01 
REQ2037354.RITM2335400.01
```

I have a database table:
**Master_Transaction_Log**

...which has three particular columns of interest:

```
Timestamp
Scan_Code
Transaction_Type
```

I would like to end up with *TWO* collections:

```
SC_ReturnToDepot
Result
REQ1991799.RITM2280596.01 

SC_Remainder_1
Result
REQ2048874.RITM2349401.01 
REQ2037354.RITM2335400.01
```

The criteria is as follows: for any given Result in **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList**, if:

A database record has Scan_Code = Result *AND* Transaction_Type = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Equipment Returning to Depot" *AND* Timestamp > 72 hours ago, then that value of Result is added to **SC_ReturnToDepot**

**SC_Remainder_1** are *all remaining values* that do not fit the above criteria.

I got as far as this so far, but it's killin' me after this:

```
            ClearCollect(SC_ReturnToDepot,
              ForAll(ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,
                ...?
              );
            );
```

I have a feeling if I can just nail that *one single line of code*, I am off to the races, but this is just... ugh, my brain is being a jerk.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-

**Longer more detailed explanation:**

I'm trying to create a mechanism that takes a list of Scan Codes from a physical in-field process (*scanning codes on boxes on a shelf*), and for each Code, and reviews a SQL database table (**Master_Transaction_Log**), looking for that code. It creates another Collection that includes those associated Scan Codes, in an *exclusive* fashion.

At a high level:

Collection **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList**, which contains one column **Result**, must be split out into the seven different lists, below. These lists are in *a specific sequence* (because we send communications in a specific sequence):

1. Collection Name: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_ReturnToDepotImmediately** - Criteria: If there is an entry in the database table where **Scan_Code** = the given Scan Code, where **Transaction_Type** = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Equipment Returning to Depot" and where **Timestamp** is older than 48 hours. - Notes: The technician will be instructed to immediately place this item into an outgoing bin for pickup. - Data Note: This Scan Code must not be included in any Collection *below this one* on this list.
2. Collection Name: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_AnnounceRemovalOfItem** - Criteria: If there is an entry in the database table where **Scan_Code** = the given Scan Code, where **Transaction_Type** = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Final Warning" and where **Timestamp** is older than 48 hours. - Notes: The customer receives an email for these items, announcing that the items will be returned to the Depot. - Data Note: This Scan Code must not be included in any Collection *below
   this one* on this list.
3. Collection Name: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_SendFinalWarning** - Criteria: If there is an entry in the database table where **Scan_Code** = the given Scan Code, where **Transaction_Type** = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Warning" and where **Timestamp** is older than 48 hours. - Notes: The customer receives an email for these items, announcing that this is their last chance to pick them up. - Data Note: This Scan Code must not be included in any Collection *below this one* on this list.
4. Collection Name: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_SendFirstWarning** - Criteria: If there is an entry in the database table where **Scan_Code** = the given Scan Code, where **Transaction_Type** = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Reminder" and where **Timestamp** is older than 48 hours. -  Notes: The customer receives an email for these items, announcing that this is a warning to pick them up. - Data Note: This Scan Code must not be included in any Collection *below this one* on this list.
5. Collection Name: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_SendReminder** - Criteria: If there is an entry in the database table where **Scan_Code** = the given Scan Code, where **Transaction_Type** = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: First Contact" and where **Timestamp** is older than 48 hours. - Notes: The customer receives an email for these items, announcing that this is a reminder to collect their order. - Data Note: This Scan Code must not be included in any Collection *below this one* on this list.
6. Collection Name: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_SendFirstContact** - Criteria: If there is an entry in the database table where **Scan_Code** = the given Scan Code and where **Transaction_Type** = "New Equipment Delivery - Received at Stockroom/Tech Bar". (note: no time delay -- this should go out immediately upon arriving at a location) - Notes: The customer receives an email for these, announcing the orders are ready to pick up.
7. Collection Name: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_NoActionTaken** - Criteria: The given Scan Code (**Result**) has not been added to any of the items above, based on previous logical rules. For example, a Reminder might have been sent, but it was sent only ten hours ago, so we *take no action* on this item.

Each of these COLLECTIONS only needs a single column: **Result**.
It's important that no single Scan Code *reside in more than one collection* -- they are built to address an *escalating notification sequence*. For example, a Scan Code for an item that has been on a shelf for a week may already have a First Contact sent, a Reminder sent, and a Warning sent. It must *ONLY* go into the **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_SendFinalWarning** Collection, because all items in that Collection will be sent Final Warnings.

I already have written the parts of the program that generates and sends the appropriate emails (including householding, which was a tough nut to crack). I think all I need is to be able to split my Master Collection into these sub-Collections and then I can simply attack each sub-Collection using its own ForAll loop.

I would dearly dearly appreciate advice on this! And of course, I'm happy to offer clarifications where needed.

-=-=-=-=-

*Larger perspective: Right now, our techs organize incoming physical boxes across different physical shelves, and each day they move sections of boxes and perform different comms based on shelf. For example, Shelf #3 gets Reminders sent, and then all items are moved to Shelf #4 for the next day. But as our production system ramps up, more boxes arrive each day. So instead of having the technicians determine which comm to send based on which shelf, and moving dozens of boxes each day, I just want them to scan the entire room and then let the tool look into the database and decide what is the next most appropriate comm to send. This will save them about 20-40 minutes a day. Furthermore, in the near future, once this system is working well, I plan to centralize comms from a single technician, instead of each tech at each remote location performing this function. But later, later...*

Comment: Are you storing information in Dataverse, a SQL Server database, MongoDB?...
If it would be for example SQL server you could query your database on start with conditions, i.e. SELECT * FROM dbo.MasterDatabase where datecreated >= today() - 48 hours.

This could be for example subcollection 1, but it depends on how your system works..

A different approach would be to do a forall and use an if-fucntion to guide which subcollection should the collect be adhered to. It all depends on where data is coming form.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it was a SQL database. I’ve updated the question. :)

Comment: You already have the criteria for when it belongs to a certain set. In your app, the galleries can have the appropriate filtering I.e. Filter( dbo, criteria 1). Same for the others. No need to collect one major table and than split into 6 and having basically double data in your app. Let SQL handle that, it’s built for that :)

Comment: I already have single householding routines for each of the different functions. Each householding routine expects the data in a single collection as described above. Once I have these six collections, then for each of these collections, I will perform the ForAll loop that households and sends emails.